# Write the result (a fraction) of a calculation with sagetex

Tags: formatting, sagetex

I made this code to add two random fractions, and calculate the result with sage, but I don't know how to make the result appear with the form `\displaystyle\dfrac{}{}`

```
\begin{sagesilent}
output = r"\begin{multicols}{4}"
output += r"\begin{itemize}"
for i in range (4):
    a = [Integer(randint(1,3)), Integer(randint(2,4)), Integer(randint(3,5)), Integer(randint(4,6))]
    output += r"\item $\dfrac{{{}}}{{{}}}+\dfrac{{{}}}{{{}}}={}$".format(Integer(a[0]), Integer(a[1]), Integer(a[2]), Integer(a[3]), Integer(a[0])/Integer(a[1])+Integer(a[2])/Integer(a[3]))
output += r"\end{itemize}"
output += r"\end{multicols}"
\end{sagesilent}
    
\sagestr{output}
```

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could compute the result first (`b` below — sorry, not the most evocative name) and then plug its numerator and denominator into `\dfrac`:

```
\begin{sagesilent}
output = r"\begin{multicols}{4}"
output += r"\begin{itemize}"
for i in range (4):
    a = [Integer(randint(1,3)), Integer(randint(2,4)), Integer(randint(3,5)), Integer(randint(4,6))]
    b = a[0]/a[1] + a[2]/a[3]
    output += r"\item $\dfrac{{{}}}{{{}}}+\dfrac{{{}}}{{{}}}=\dfrac{{{}}}{{{}}}$".format(a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], b.numerator(), b.denominator())
output += r"\end{itemize}"
output += r"\end{multicols}"
\end{sagesilent}
    
\sagestr{output}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I want. I didn't know this possibility.

Comment: There is also a `is_integer()` command in the documentation [here](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/rings_standard/sage/rings/integer.html). If case the answer is an integer, print the answer. Otherwise get numerator and denominator.

Comment: Thank you. I'm discovering sage, and I with your reference I start to understand the importance of the integer class, and all its features.

Answer (score 1):

I found an other possibility by using `latex()` function, which return a latex expression.

```
\begin{sagesilent}
output = r"\begin{multicols}{4}"
output += r"\begin{itemize}"
for i in range (4):
    a = [Integer(randint(1,3)), Integer(randint(2,4)), Integer(randint(3,5)), Integer(randint(4,6))]
    f1 = a[0]/a[1]
    f2 = a[2]/a[3]
    f = f1 + f2
    output += r"\item $\displaystyle{}+\displaystyle{}=\displaystyle{}$".format(latex(f1), latex(f2), latex(f))
output += r"\end{itemize}"
output += r"\end{multicols}"
\end{sagesilent}

\sagestr{output}
```